# Allow Widget Space to Expand Into

Tags: flutter

I'm building a form in Flutter and I've sort of found some solutions for what i'm looking for, but they don't feel quite right.

What I'd like to be able to do is to give form field a margin that it can expand into without altering the space taken up by the margin that is enclosing the widget. The reason i'd like to to this is because flutter form fields change height when the validator error text is shown.

The solution I've found currently is to use a container with a specified height which will be enough for the `TextFormField` to expand into when the error text is shown:

```dart
return Container(
      height: 100,
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: label),
        validator: (_) => 'Placeholder error text'
      ),
    );
```

It works, but I don't really like this solution though because you have to know in advance how tall the `TextFormField` is going to be once it is expanded. So for example if the `maxLines` property is changed to 10, then you also have to mess around with the container height until you find the height that is right for it.

Is there a solution which allows you to provide some excess space that the widget can expand into without changing the total height or the excess space plus the widget height?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the text form field inside a flexible widget.

```
return Column(
   children: <Widget>[
   Flexible(
    child:Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),    
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: label),
        validator: (_) => 'Placeholder error text'
      ),
     ),
    ),
   ],
  );
```

Comment: hmmmm I feel like this might be on the right track and it does work in a simple setup, but the column i'm using is inside a `SingleChildScrollView` which is freaking out when a `Flexible` is used inside it. It's throwing errors about `RenderBox was not laid out` because of the `Flexible`'s unbounded size I guess.

Comment: So I got this working, but unfortunately the validation text still causes the whole Flexible widget to expand. What I want is for the outer widget to allow the text form field to change size without the outer one changing size.